# Get posts order by meta_value_num with two meta keys

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get post by `get_post` order by meta_value_num and meta keys , I tried this code:

```
get_posts(
    array(  'post_type' => 'posts',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array('key' => 'class'),
            array('key' => 'chair')
         )
    )
);
```

I want to get the post sort by class's number then chair's number .
but htis code not working how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Although the new `orderby` parameter is great in `WP_Query`, it does not support multiple `orderby` for multiple `meta_key`'s.

I've went through a couple of scenarios and even went and digged into trac and make and came up with the following

- make.wordpress.org [A more powerful orderby in wordpress 4.0](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/)
- [trac ticket #17065](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065)

None of the issues regarding this very problem have been answered. It also seems from those two links that there is an issue ordering by a `meta_key` and another field like post date for instance. I haven't tried this as yet.

I truelly think that you have two choices here without creating two queries.

- hack using the `posts_orderby` filter as described by @s_ha_dum in his answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101599/31545)
- By making use of PHP ordering using `usort`. The idea here would be to sort your query by one `meta_key` and then take the returned posts array ($posts) and sort them by the second `meta_key` before the loop starts. You can either use the `the_posts` filter (just remember to remove the filter once done) or simply unset `$posts` in your template and set it with the reordered array of posts once done